# In a RoR project, where does all the library files sit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Where are all the files? I see (as expected) that my controllers/models etc inherit from other classes, where can I see the actual code of those classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to find those classes on your machine, you have to go to the directory where ruby is installed and look for the gems directory. On my machine that is:

> /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems

I just made a screenshot so that you can see where is everything. You can [see it here](http://www.imagup.com/data/1114650059.html). As you know, Rails is made up of many components (Active Record, Active Support, Action Mailer, Active Resource etc.) and each component has its own directory.

Answer (score 0):

The code is in the rails gem. All the code is available in the [Rails repository](http://github.com/rails/rails). There is usually no need to dive into the code, though, and the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org) & [official API](http://api.rubyonrails.org) are almost always sufficient.

Comment: Counterpoint: the source code is pleasantly concise, and I already have gobs of tools for working with text files and source code (and comparatively few for navigating api-docs-in-a-web-browser).  There is usually no need to use the web documentation, as the source code is always sufficient.  :-)

Comment: The web documentation does allow for viewing the source for each method inline. Also, you can use `ri` or `rdoc` to view documentation from the command line.

Comment: Yeah, and it's sometimes nice those things exist, but my web browser is still worse than my text editor at navigating source code.  The day that stops being true is the day I'll be writing code in my web browser.

Answer (score 0):

for reference, you might try the [open_gem gem](https://github.com/adamsanderson/open_gem).  This adds a gem subcommand 'open', which will open an installed gem's root in your editor of choice. I often use the following command to open gems in textmate on os x:

```
gem open some_obscure_gem -c mate
```